# What should be the type of parameter in Typescript which take Array of Obj in a functional component Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, types, custom-data-type

```
const Form = ({ arrayValue }: any): JSX.Element => {
    console.log("Array of Obj",arrayValue)
    
    //It is a form big form component....
});
```

`arrayValue` is an array of objects where the item is large in number, how can I remove **any** type and give a particular type to these components?

Answer (score 0):

You  have several ways to do it:

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react'

type Obj = {
  name: string
}

type Props = {
  arrayValue: Obj[]
}

const Form: FC<Props> = ({ arrayValue }) => {
  console.log("Array of Obj", arrayValue)
  const x = arrayValue[0].name // ok
  return <div></div>

  //It is a form big form component....
};

// OR GENERIC WAY

const Form2 = <T,>({ arrayValue }: { arrayValue: T[] }) => {
  console.log("Array of Obj", arrayValue)
  return <div></div>

  //It is a form big form component....
};
type Obj2 = { age: number }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwnAL5wBmUEIcA5FKhrQFDMwCeYScA8gEYArOAF5czOHAB2KEEgBccAM4wowSQHNmJVhy5wAClTCKRYiSihQU7AGooANgFd5vQQG0AultZoIk5QTQIApEADyGEMYAfKYAFHgWVrYOzqQAlCIxOOJwvv4Q9kgAdPYQ6rEARACCltZwEOSuAhXYidZ2TkhpOXkBAB6mbcmdbgAMHkXSsnAA9DP1ANY5DDCOUJJwoQAmwABuUaEzO-usEnMAkvDAJigUQXB8wOp3UDS%204H5IkjBFv0VaAG5WHNeAg4ABxACiADlIQhzsQAOpVACaPj8AXwQQATKZQgAVTBReJwIYdVIkBQJWrDZwKfGedKZMy5DEFYqlcrVGn1Rr8ZqtGnkrrLJCrdabY4HI57KKnWYzS5wa6kl40R7Pcj3d6QSRfH5-QFsTjcfm40QJdQuSSOEB8JBQUjo-zwBiKRz2eCiUJY17Y0JmmJklJIYQ4NyWlwAFlxJA8ZBmUSAA)

Please keep in mind, `generic way` has own drawbacks. You can't refer to property of specific element in the array, but you can provide some restrictions (bounds) for `T` argument.

For example:

```js
const Form2 = <T extends { age: number }>({ arrayValue }: { arrayValue: T[] }) => {
  console.log("Array of Obj", arrayValue)
  arrayValue[0].age // ok
  return <div></div>

  //It is a form big form component....
};
type Obj2 = { age: number }

const result = <Form2<Obj2> arrayValue={[{ age: '42' }]} /> // error, because age ahouls be a number
```